# Are two queries with second by ID faster than one with hash?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a table with two columns, `id` and `uniqueId`, the `uniqueId` is a `TEXT` field generated using PHP's `uniqid` function. Users never are given the actual `id` on the client-side, for security/privacy reasons.

So a common scenario is for a user to request more details, or child fields from another table for a resource by the uniqueId which they have.

My question is this, specifically I have a query that will be looking up 50-100 entries in a table, is it faster to simply perform the lookup using the uniqueId, which is something like `55ea74bc12a661.02727647`, or to first do a query to find the original ID (simple auto-increment column), and then perform the lookup using that?

Comment: The fastest possible lookup using MySQL and InnoDB is when you use the primary key - in your case, the lookup via auto_increment is the fastest and nothing is faster than that.

Comment: I suppose the question is then whether that's worth incurring the overhead of an extra query.

Comment: If you add the queries you're running, we might be able to help you. This way, it's just speculating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. The user is coming at the code with the long, 'random', uniqueId.  You need to look that up.
2. When JOINing tables and doing other lookups, you need a unique id (either `id` or `uniqueId`) to join with.

Step 1: uniqueId may as well be the PRIMARY KEY of the `Users` table.  It can also have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id for my point #2.  (more in a minute.)  Being the PK achieves the point that N.B. brought up.

```
uniqueId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET ascii,  -- not TEXT, not utf8
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(uniqueId),
INDEX(id)  -- Yes, auto_inc will work with this
```

This gives you the mapping from `uniqueId` to `id`, plus gets to the User's basic info on your first `SELECT`.

Step 2: Now you will be `JOINing` to other tables using `id`.  Or doing separate `SELECTs` using `id`.  Why not simply use uniqueId everywhere?

- `id` is much smaller--only 4 bytes. Contrast `uniqueId`--up to 257 bytes.
- "newer" users will have "higher" ids.  This will tend to 'cluster' the active users together, making things more cacheable.  (I am assuming that "older" users mostly drop off the face of the earth.)

Comment: Thanks for putting my question better than I had, also, I think your tip about making it a VARCHAR in ASCII will have a huge impact on my performance, so thanks for that.